# Finding specific x value when y axis is zero

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, interpolation

If I have the following data:

https://pastebin.com/4F7R0nW0

Which plotted using `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{80, 110}, {-0.020, 0.05}}]` gives:

[image]

Question:

How can I find the value of the x axis where the y axis is zero in the left part of the curve (Red dot in the curve)?. It looks like this value is around 88 but I would like to find it automatically and be more precise.

I tried something like interpolating the data first such as: `interp = Interpolation[data]` and then used `FindRoot` such as `root = FindRoot[interp == 0, {x, 70}][[1, 2]]` but this does not work.

Comment: First, when using the full data file there are two roots near x=80, so starting the search at x=70 would be expected to find them before the root you want.  Second, use `interp[x]` instead of `interp`, as in `FindRoot[interp[x] == 0, {x, 90}]`

Comment: @LouisB thank you very much! I knew there was something simple I was doing wrong. I appreciate very much your input (+1). Do you know if there is any way to restrictict it to be do this search from say 87 to 91 only?

Comment: Check the Details and Options section of the  [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) documentation, please, for how to specify a min / max search range.  And let us know if you have any problem implementing it.

Comment: `ArgMin[{interp[x]^2, 87 < x < 91}, x]`